# Htaccess remove word and some string from url

Tags: .htaccess

I have discovered that some visitors to my site connect with a weird URL:

Example: http://www.example.com/article/?epik=3xFD_XXs

The trouble is, when "?epik=3xFD_XXs" is added to a URL, it causes me to lose ads on my website!

So, I would really like to find a solution.

I'm presuming that the solution would be to redirect them to the original URL, http://www.example.com/article/, whenever ?epik=Random_char is found.

Thank you.

Comment: Any idea why users are hitting this url? We have the same thing and it's hundreds of requests per second. It's not about ads for us, it's bringing down the site. No idea where they are coming from.

Answer (score 0):

This `RewriteCond` is to check whether the request query string contains `epik=`. If it contains the query string `epik=`, the `RewriteRule` redirect is then applied. The `?` character is used to remove query string if any.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} epik=
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}? [R,L]
```